# What does "spreading one original pixel into multiple ones" mean in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, pixel, resolution

I'm reading [this article](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio) on the `PixelRatio` class in React Native. It says "iOS tries to be as faithful as possible to the user value by spreading one original pixel into multiple ones to trick the eye".

What does this mean? Does it mean that if you set something to be 1.9 in size, it will "spread" the element to be 2 pixels? If so, would it round 1.4px down to 1px?

Answer (score 0):

First it's important to remember that size you set is measured not in pixels but in density-independent pixels - a magic value that will be later transformed into pixels based on device pixel ratio

Pixel spreading would mean that, if 1.4 pixels wide red line needs to be rendered, it would come out as 1 solid red pixel + 1 partially red pixel to look less than 2 and more than 1. Another example - imagine red line that starts at x = 100.5 and ends at x = 101.5 - which would be 1 pixel wide but spread across 2 pixels. Usually you would get 2 half red pixels next to each other, but thanks to react native, it will round final values the way that this line snaps to either one or another pixel, resulting in 1 pixel width solid red